# necesito implementar un codigo para un boton tkinter donde este no se active hasta llenar el formulario entero

Tags: python, formularios, tkinter, validación, botón

amigos tengo el sgt codigo

```
from tkinter import *
raiz =Tk()
raiz.title("hola mundo")
raiz.iconbitmap("F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\Archivos py\Con-Exceptions\TKINTER\imagenes\images.ico")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg ="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = Frame(raiz,bg="white",width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill ="both",expand = "True")

correo = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

nombrelable = Label(miframe,text ="Cuenta de Correo:",font =(16))
nombrelable.grid(row="1",column="0")
passlabel = Label(miframe,text ="Contraseña:",font =(16))
passlabel.grid(row="2",column="0")
textocorreo= Entry(miframe,width="30",textvariable =correo)
textocorreo.grid(row="1",column="1")
textopass= Entry(miframe,width="30",textvariable =password,)
textopass.grid(row="2",column="1")


def send_data():
    correo_info = correo.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    newfile = open("clientes.txt", "a")
    newfile.write(correo_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.write(password_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.close()
    textocorreo.delete(0,END)
    textopass.delete(0, END)

ingresarboton=Button(miframe, text="Ingresar", command= send_data)
ingresarboton.grid(row="11",column="1")

raiz.mainloop()
```

lo que necesito es que al lanzar esta aplicacion yo no pueda dar click en el boton ingresar hasta tanto no llenar todos los campos de correo y password,,,pensando en que voy a introducir varias cuantas de correo con sus password respectivo,,,es que si se dan cuenta esto se guardara en un txt y si doy click sin haber llenado los datos esto me genera lineas dentro del txt y no lo deseo,,lo que deseo es lanzar la aplicacion,que el boton este descativado o que al pulsar diga algun mensaje de error,,,llenar los datos y que se active,pulsar y que luego se vuelva a desactivar hasta que vuelva a poner otros datos,,,no se si me hago entender

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias posibilidades, pero las dos que mencionas las puedes implementar de forma simple.

## Usar las StringVars para validar el formulario

Una forma muy simple de deshabilitar el botón y solo habilitarlo cuando el formulario sea válido es usar las `StringVars` y su método `trace_add` para asociar una callback que sea llamada cada vez que son modificadas. Lugo podemos comprobar si los requisitos para que el formulario sea válido se cumplen o no y habilitar o deshabilitar el botón en consecuencia:

```
import tkinter as tk


def send_data():
    correo_info = correo.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    newfile = open("clientes.txt", "a")
    newfile.write(correo_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.write(password_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.close()
    textocorreo.delete(0,  tk.END)
    textopass.delete(0, tk.END)

def form_validate(var, indx, mode):
    if correo.get() and password.get():
        ingresarboton.configure(state="normal")
    else:
        ingresarboton.configure(state="disabled")

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title("hola mundo")
#raiz.iconbitmap("F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\Archivos py\Con-Exceptions\TKINTER\imagenes\images.ico")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = tk.Frame(raiz, bg="white", width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

correo = tk.StringVar(raiz)
password = tk.StringVar(raiz)
correo.trace_add("write",  form_validate)
password.trace_add("write",  form_validate)

nombrelable = tk.Label(miframe, text="Cuenta de Correo:", font=16)
nombrelable.grid(row=1, column=0)
passlabel = tk.Label(miframe, text ="Contraseña:", font=(16))
passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
textocorreo= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=correo)
textocorreo.grid(row=1, column=1)
textopass= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=password)
textopass.grid(row=2, column=1)

ingresarboton = tk.Button(
    miframe, text="Ingresar", command=send_data, state="disabled")
ingresarboton.grid(row=11, column=1)

raiz.mainloop()
```

## Usar la callback del botón para validar y lanzar un mensaje

Puedes usar la propia callback asociada al botón para que directamente o derivando en otra función, valide el formulario. Si algun campo falta o los datos no son correctos, lanzar un `messagebox` informando y no procesar el formulario.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def send_data():
    if not form_validate():
        return 
    correo_info = correo.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    newfile = open("clientes.txt", "a")
    newfile.write(correo_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.write(password_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.close()
    textocorreo.delete(0,  tk.END)
    textopass.delete(0, tk.END)

def form_validate():
    mail = correo.get()
    passw = password.get()
    if passw and mail:
        return True
    elif passw and not mail:
        msg = "El campo de la correo no puede estar vacío"
    elif not passw and mail:
        msg = "El campo de la contraseña no puede estar vacío"
    else:
        msg = "Debe rellenar los campos del correo y la contraseña"
    messagebox.showerror("Error", msg)
    return False

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title("hola mundo")
#raiz.iconbitmap("F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\Archivos py\Con-Exceptions\TKINTER\imagenes\images.ico")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = tk.Frame(raiz, bg="white", width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

correo = tk.StringVar(raiz)
password = tk.StringVar(raiz)

nombrelable = tk.Label(miframe, text="Cuenta de Correo:", font=16)
nombrelable.grid(row=1, column=0)
passlabel = tk.Label(miframe, text ="Contraseña:", font=(16))
passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
textocorreo= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=correo)
textocorreo.grid(row=1, column=1)
textopass= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=password)
textopass.grid(row=2, column=1)

ingresarboton = tk.Button(
    miframe, text="Ingresar", command=send_data)
ingresarboton.grid(row=11, column=1)

raiz.mainloop()
```

En ambos casos, para simplificar, solo se valida que los Entries no estén vacíos, pero puedes usar los métodos para validar que el campo del correo mediante una expresión regular por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

buenos dias por que si agrego un nuevo boton al codigo digamos algo como

```
ingresarboton=tk.Button(miframe, text="Comenzar Proceso", command= comenzar)
ingresarboton.grid(row="12",column="1")
```

La propiedad de validar la coje este boton y no el anterior que es el que deseo que se valide
por ejemplo,

```
def send_data():
    correo_info = correo.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    newfile = open("clientes.txt", "a")
    newfile.write(correo_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.write(password_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.close()
    textocorreo.delete(0,  tk.END)
    textopass.delete(0, tk.END)

def form_validate(var, indx, mode):
    if correo.get() and password.get():
        ingresarboton.configure(state="normal")
    else:
        ingresarboton.configure(state="disabled")

def comenzar():
    pass

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title("hola mundo")
#raiz.iconbitmap("F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\Archivos py\Con-Exceptions\TKINTER\imagenes\images.ico")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = tk.Frame(raiz, bg="white", width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

correo = tk.StringVar(raiz)
password = tk.StringVar(raiz)
correo.trace_add("write",  form_validate)
password.trace_add("write",  form_validate)

nombrelable = tk.Label(miframe, text="Cuenta de Correo:", font=16)
nombrelable.grid(row=1, column=0)
passlabel = tk.Label(miframe, text ="Contraseña:", font=(16))
passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
textocorreo= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=correo)
textocorreo.grid(row=1, column=1)
textopass= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=password)
textopass.grid(row=2, column=1)

ingresarboton = tk.Button(miframe, text="Ingresar", command=send_data, state="disabled")
ingresarboton.grid(row=11, column=1)
ingresarboton=tk.Button(miframe, text="Comenzar Proceso", command= comenzar,state="disabled")
ingresarboton.grid(row="12",column="1")

raiz.mainloop()
```

en este codigo quien toma la propiedad de activarse o no es el boton de comenzar proceso cuando lo que quiero es que la tome es el de ingresar,,si eleimino el boton de comenzar proceso entoces la propiedad de validar si la toma en de ingresar ,,,por que?

Comment: la respuesta me ayudo a resolver el problema q tenia, lo q no entiendo xq en la función def form_validate(var, indx, mode): le pasan esos 3 parámetros, de donde salen?